# How to web resource to all forms?

Tags: html, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I know how to add **Web Resource** (html/js/image) to particular entity or form like *Contacs*, *Account*, even custom entity, or dash board. But problem is we want to show Web Resource on each and every form/entity of dynamics CRM.

We are not allowed to use popup.

Please consider we are using Online Dynamics CRM (and not on premise).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add manually the web resource to each form of each entity.
There isn't an option or a tool to perform this task.